# Hibernate freezes at transaction begin function

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Hibernate on my server, (tomcat8, hibernate, postgresql).
Every end of the day my code runs (using Quartz) some code, which calls inside the stored procedure (hibernate):

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
        throws JobExecutionException {
    log.info("=========Start daily update==========");
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    boolean transactionCompleted = false;
    int retryCount = HibernateUtil.RETRY_COUNT;

    HibernateUtil.closeCurrentEntityManager();

    EntityManager em = HibernateUtil.currentEntityManager();

    while (!transactionCompleted)
    {
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            dailyUpdateDao.dailyUpdate();
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            transactionCompleted = true;
        } catch (PersistenceException ex) {
            if (!HibernateUtil.isDeadlockException(ex) || retryCount == 0) {
                log.error("non deadlock error", ex);
                throw ex;
            }

            log.error("deadlock detected. Retrying {}", HibernateUtil.RETRY_COUNT - retryCount);
            retryCount--;
            if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                em.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(HibernateUtil.sleepIntervalWhenDeadlockDetected(retryCount));
            } catch(Exception sleepex) {
                log.error("non deadlock sleep ex", ex);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }

    log.info("===========Daily Update Job Completed ============== It took {} ms", System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
}
```

The dailyUpdate function in the code above is doing the following:

```
public void dailyUpdate() {
    String sql = "select count(*) FROM daily_update()";
    EntityManager em = HibernateUtil.currentEntityManager();
    em.createNativeQuery(sql).getSingleResult();
}
```

(calling stored procedure using native sql through hibernate).

When I run the server, it does first 2 or 3 calls normally. Next calls never finishes. I reproduced the issue locally, instead of each day I put the schedule to start the task each 1 minute. It showed me logs like this:

> Daily Update Job Completed ============== It took 7338 ms
>
> Daily Update Job Completed ============== It took 6473 ms
>
> ...
>
> Daily Update Job Completed ============== It took 183381 ms

so the delay increased and I decided to see whats going on inside.
In the code above, when it tries to execute the

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
```

it never finishes and the stack trace is shown below as an image:

[image: Stacktrace of frozen execution]

What is the reason and how to resolve the problem?

**EDIT 1:** currentEntityManager and closeCurrentEntityManager codes:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
...
private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENT_UNIT);
public static EntityManager currentEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf)
        throws HibernateException {
    EntityManager em = (EntityManager) entityManager.get();
    if (em == null||!em.isOpen()) {

        em = emf.createEntityManager();

        entityManager.set(em);
    }
    return em;
}

public static void closeCurrentEntityManager() {
    EntityManager s = (EntityManager) entityManager.get();
    try {
        if (s != null) {
            if (s.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                if (s.getTransaction().getRollbackOnly()) {
                    s.getTransaction().rollback();
                } else {
                    s.getTransaction().commit();
                }
            }
            s.close();
        }
    } finally {
        entityManager.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `HibernateUtil` and how do `closeCurrentEntityManager()` and `currentEntityManager()` work?

Comment: @Andremoniy updated the question. Please take a look.

Comment: What is `entityManager` field inside this class?

Comment: @Andremoniy its there in the code: ThreadLocal<EntityManager> entityManager = new ThreadLocal<EntityManager>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, perfect, after posting details about what is `HibernateUtil`, how do `closeCurrentEntityManager()` and `currentEntityManager()` work, and what is `entityManager` fiels inside this class, everything becomes clear.

Look at your code. You firstly closes "current" entity manager:

`HibernateUtil.closeCurrentEntityManager();`

But you should take into consideration that fact that `quartz scheduller` starts its tasks in different threads. So

```
public static void closeCurrentEntityManager() {
    EntityManager s = (EntityManager) entityManager.get();
```

will return `null` (if it is new thread).

Next step you invoke

```
 EntityManager em = HibernateUtil.currentEntityManager();
```

which also will create new `EntityManager` as it is new thread:

```
em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Now look at you screenshot: your `beginTransaction()` methods awaits for new connection. What's happening here is that you create new entitmanager which opens new connection, but do not close it. So basically your are out of free connections in you pool.

Simply try move `HibernateUtil.closeCurrentEntityManager();` into `final { ... }`block and test again.

Comment: Oh, I thought I did it, but incorrectly putting it in the beginning... Thank you!